# Use Enum.Parse with char enum

Tags: c#

```
public enum Color
{
    Red = 'R',
    Blue = 'B',
    Green = 'G',
    Yellow = 'Y',
}

Color color = (Color)Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), "R");
```

Hello community!

I tried to parse an string value with an char enum, but it throws me an System.ArgumentException.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `Enum.Parse` will convert the string "Red" to the enum value.  To convert the character 'R' to the enum value, just cast it: `(Color)'R'`

Comment: @BJMyers Of course that approach lacks error handling.

Comment: @BJMyers But I want to convert the string to the enum value.

Comment: For a start `"R" != 'R'`. Then char enums aren't really practical. It may be worth to use `const` fields instead (see wpf [Colors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors(v=vs.110).aspx)), though we don't know what is the purpose of `Color` enum which has values like `Red = 'R'`.

Comment: @MattD Enum.Parse does not take a char as a parameter.

Comment: If you try to print the value : _Console.WriteLine(Color.Red)_ - you will find that you get "Red", not 'R'. So you need to do the opposite _(Color)Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), "Red")_ will work without an Exception. Or _Color color = (Color)'R';_

Comment: Do you have a specific purpose for using those `char` values instead of `int` values? What are you trying to do?

Comment: If I remember correctly even if you assign char literals these get implicitly typecasted to ints. So your enum is actually an int enum. Therefore for Enum.Parse you also need to cast your chars to int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that C# does not support `char` as an underlying type for enumerations.  It is illegal to declare an enum like this:

```
public enum Color : char
```

The underlying type of your `Color` enum is actually `int`, since no other type is specified in its declaration.

C# will, however, allow you to assign a character literal as the value of an enum member - by converting it to the corresponding ASCII integer.  So your `Color` enum declaration is identical to this:

```
public enum Color
{
    Red = 82,
    Blue = 66,
    Green = 71,
    Yellow = 89,
}
```

If you think of the enumeration in terms of integral values, the problem becomes a bit clearer.  There is no relationship between the string `"R"` and `Color.Red`.  There *is* a relationship between the *character* `'R'` and `Color.Red`, but only because the character is (implicitly) converted to its ASCII representation.

`Enum.Parse` is designed to convert a `string` to an enumeration based on the *name* of the declared enum member, not its value.  Therefore, `Enum.Parse` will only work if you want to convert `"Red"` to `Color.Red`.  To convert the character `R` (i.e. the number 89) to `Color.Red`, you simply cast it to the enum type:

```
Color red = (Color)'R';
```

If your goal is to convert the string `"R"` to `Color.Red`, you would need to convert it to a `char` by treating the string as a character array:

```
Color red = (Color)"R"[0];
```

Methods such as `Enum.IsDefined` could be used beforehand to determined whether the input is a valid enum value.  But as noted in comments above, this isn't really how enums are designed to be used.  A `char`-ish enum may be the wrong tool for the job.